# How to handle error raise - Asyncio in Python3

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've got a function `f()` that makes an API call and I want to call it multiple times asynchronously. I use the `asyncio` lib like that:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, f) for i in range(10)]
    await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    return futures

result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

The problem is that sometimes `f()` raises an `Exception` and I'm not sure how to handle it. The doc says that `Futures` can contain an `Exception`, but that's not the case here, error is raised and program crashes.

How do I achieve that ? I think I could write a wrapper for `f()` and `try: catch:` the Exception, but that seems ugly if the feature is provided by the lib.

Thanks in advance for help,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The problem is that sometimes `f()` raises an `Exception` and I'm not sure how to handle it.

That will depend on what you want to do when an exception occurs. Remember that `asyncio.gather()` is convenience API that propagates exceptions by default to avoid blindly continuing in case of error. If you *want* to proceed in case of exception, you have other options:

- Pass `return_exceptions=True` to `gather` - this will cause `gather` to return the exception objects along with other results. Convenient and easy to use, but mixes exceptions with regular results, which is a bit messy.
- Use `asyncio.wait()` instead of `asyncio.gather()`. It returns sets of *futures*, each of which you can test whether it completed by raising or by producing a result.
- Wrap `f()` in your own function that catches the exception as you see fit. You considered and rejected this, but in some cases it's exactly the right approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's what I was looking for. I ran a few tests don't see clearly the difference between the first 2 options, it seems to me that `gather(*futures, return_exceptions=True)` does the same thing than `wait(futures)` (except that `wait` does not respect order), in both cases exceptions are mixed with results right ? (It's not a problem for my usecase, just to understand. Marked as solved)

Comment: @MeanStreet The difference is that `wait()` returns sets of [*futures*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future). Given a future, you can extract its result with `result()`, which will either return the result or re-raise the exception if there was one. But you can also call [`exception()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.exception) to test whether an exception was raised. This allows you to distinguish between a function that raised an exception and one that (for whatever reason) happened to *return* an `Exception` instance.

Comment: Oh I got it, that's what you meant by "mixes exceptions with regular results". Thanks

Comment: Can you show what `gather` returns exactly? the official documentation is sooo poooor

Comment: @Pynchia If you're asking about `gather(..., return_exceptions=True)`, it will return exception objects for tasks that raise. For example, given `async def div(n): return 10 / n`, the expression `await asyncio.gather(*(div(i) for i in range(10)), return_exceptions=True)` will evaluate to `[ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'), 10.0, 5.0, 3.3333333333333335, 2.5, 2.0, 1.6666666666666667, 1.4285714285714286, 1.25, 1.1111111111111112]`. Without `return_exceptions=True` the `await gather(...)` would just raise the exception and you'd be unable to observe the successful results.

Comment: @user4815162342 many thanks. Yes, I need to discriminate the returned values from the exceptions. I was hoping `gather` would return an iterable of tuples, e.g. `(Exception, Retval)`. Instead it looks like one needs to discriminate by type-checking

Comment: @Pynchia Yes, you can discriminate using `isinstance(val, Exception)`. If some of your coroutines wanted to actually _return_ exception objects (which is not a common thing to do, but is certainly possible), that kind of discrimination would fail. This is what I meant in the answer by mixing results with exceptions being messy.

Comment: @Pynchia Also note that nothing stops you from writing a trivial wrapper that awaits the given coroutine and catches exceptions - for example: `async def wrap(fut): try: return (await fut, None) except Exception as e: return (None, e)`. Then you can await `gather(*(wrap(coro(...) for coro in coros))` without `return_exceptions` and retain precise distinction between tasks that raised and those that finished.